# Is it possible to store a KeyValuePair of a dictionary without the use of a foreach loop?

Tags: c#

The syntax for iterating over a dictionary with a foreach loop is:

> foreach (KeyValuePair<key, value> item in dictionary)

Inside the foreach loop the key is accessed with item.key and the value with item.value.

This got me thinking, can this be used without the use of a foreach loop as a convenient (although niche) way to represent a specific dictionary pair?

I am not looking for some weird work arounds, like running a foreach loop and saving the KeyValuePair into a variable once the target key is reached, because at this point it would be more convenient to just use 2 variables.

Comment: Which one do you want from the dictionary?

Comment: Does it matter? I want to be able to pick a specific one based on any key.

Comment: You can use `dictionary[key]` - that will return the value, which you can then save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this

```
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    dic["a"] = 42;
    KeyValuePair<string, int> keyVal;
    foreach(var kv in dic) {
        keyVal = kv; << gets the last entry from the dictioanry
    }
```

Note that the dictionary does not store KeyValuePairs, it creates one for the enumeration, so the simple thing to do is this (because we are not expensively recreating something)

```
   var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    dic["a"] = 42;
    KeyValuePair<string, int> keyVal = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("a", dic["a"]);
```

this is more efficient than the (neat) LINQ Sinlge method

Comment: Is this really the only way? This seems very roundabout...

Comment: @YuvalAmir You asked how to store KV pair to a variable outside the foreach loop. That variable has to be A KeyValuePiar<TK,TV> and it has to be written to. I added 2 lines, declare the variable and assign, it the rest of the code just creates a test Dictionary. It feels like you actually have a diffferent need, maybe edit the question.

Comment: Sorry I meant for a way to save those without the need for a for loop. I edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

The `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`. This means you can simply use `Single()` to get the entry you want.

```
IDictionary<string, int> dict = ...;
KeyValuePair<string, int> entry = dict.Single(it => it.Key == "yourKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    {"hi","Hello World!"},
    {"adieu","Goodby"}
    };
    

string hi = dict["hi"]; //Hello World!
```

or if you want a list

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>  list = dict.ToList();
```

result

```
[{"Key":"hi","Value":"Hello World!"},{"Key":"adieu","Value":"Goodby"}]
```